# NSLog of the current ViewController class name from AppDelegate.m

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

How can I generate NSLog from the current ViewController class name?

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{

    NSLog(self.window.rootViewController.class);

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass(self.window.rootViewController.class));
```

Comment: thanks, I just can't figure why it i picking the main viewcontroller instead of the current one

Answer (score 4):

if you're using a navigation controller you probably want something like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.visibleViewController class]);
```