# Access Current ViewController Class Name from AppDelegate.m

Tags: objective-c

How if I wanted to access the current view controller instead of the root view controller to get the class name from AppDelegate.m?

Currently, ViewController A is actually the root view of RootViewController.

I've did some research here but I only managed to get the RootViewController class name instead of ViewController one.

[NSLog of the current ViewController class name from AppDelegate.m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13409009/nslog-of-the-current-viewcontroller-class-name-from-appdelegate-m)

I've followed what the answers that provided for the question, but it returns null for
self.

```
NSLog(@"Current View Controller Class Name: %@", self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.visibleViewController.class);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"Current View Controller Class Name: %@", [self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.visibleViewController class]);
```

Comment: Are you using a UINavigationController?

Comment: What is your view controller hierarchy for the `window` property of your `AppDelegate` class.

Comment: @random Yes I am using a UINavigationController... And because I wanted to do some checking of the current view controller class name when I received notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this...

```
NSLog(@"Current View Controller Class Name: %@",NSStringFromClass(self.window.rootViewController.navigationController.visibleViewController.class));
```

Comment: Yup! I've tried this earlier, and because of it returns null so even use NSStringFromClass also it will definitely return null.